# Learning to play piano from zero

Tags: beginner

I'm 23 years old. I'm planning on buying a digital piano and learn to play on it. I know nothing about music, I'm never had any lessons on it. Is it even possible for me to learn to play on it without a teacher, just via internet? After buying a digital piano, where do I start and how do I progress. Once I learn how to play on a digital piano, will I be able to play on a real one?

Comment: [Learning piano without a teacher](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14130/learning-piano-without-a-teacher) might be helpful for you.

Comment: It is possible to learn to play purely by yourself, even without the help of the internet. It used to happen before the advent of the internet, after all! If you are willing to put your trust in sites, then you will get somewhere. Maybe better than just using books - at least you are shown what to do in real time! But rather like books (or unknown teachers), you won't be able to guarantee that a site is totally suited to you. If one is recommended, it may have been great for the recommender, but that's not you!Also, we have no clue as to how 'musical' you are.If you are, why has it been left?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. https://yousician.com. And it seems they have a 50% discount for new subscribers and a 30 day trial. I use it and it's certainly for beginners and certainly worth the small fee.

I've learned from the guitar, bass, singing and now I just bought a piano. I wish they had drumming but how many people have a midi drum set. (But it could be with just one midi pad solely to practice rhythms.)

What I like is that they have both tab and staff (real music) ... I think it's not that hard to learn to read the staff and that TAB is too much of a crutch.

You say "digital piano" ... does that mean MIDI or just that it has its own sounds and some digital display?

If you need a MIDI keyboard look at IK Multimedia iRig Keys Pro full-sized 37-key MIDI controller. Over the weekend they were 50% off ... maybe one will still give you one for $75 ... I see they're still $99 on Amazon.

Comment: How 37 keys equates to 'Pro' defeats me...

Comment: It might be useful as input device for sequencer or playing single note leads. For learning piano I'd recommend at least 73 keys. I don't really understand the point about tab for piano, sheet music basically is tab for piano.

Comment: Opps! Yes, sheet music is tab for piano! Ha!

But I don't know why you need 73 at the outset. If you need that many to learn on then do smaller options even exist, which are all presumably for experienced players.