# Learning the piano and theory without a teacher?

Tags: piano, beginner, self-learning, lessons

I recently ordered a keyboard, and I plan to buy online courses to learn the piano and theory. I can afford a teacher, however, due to some circumstances in my life, it's hard to attend the lessons at a specific time during the day. I do plan to get a piano teacher somewhere at the end of the next year.

Would it be a good idea to learn the piano and the theory online? Can I get decent at it by learning on my own? I do assume a teacher would be able to point out mistakes earlier, whereas on my own it would take more time to find out my mistakes and I might then have to unlearn those. However, since I do plan to get a teacher next year, would learning the piano and theory on my own right now still benefit me?

Some more information about me:

- I'm 26 years old
- I can practice the piano daily 45-60 minutes
- I have almost no prior knowledge of music theory, other than I do know what notes, accidentals, octaves are.

Comment: Not knowing anything about you, the best responses will be personal opinions, which won't be too helpful. This will possibly be closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning Piano without a teacher](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14130/learning-piano-without-a-teacher)

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

If you know nothing about music theory, then the theory that you'd be learning while simultaneously learning how to play the piano is relatively basic (doesn't mean it's not important, but it'll be the "addition" and "multiplication" and not the "algebra", so to speak). Because of that, I think that it'd be hard to learn wrong things. On a personal note, I HIGHLY recommend the [Faber and Faber adult piano method](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1616773022).

That being said, DO start eventually learning with a teacher, and sooner is better than later. Also, if you have the opportunity, take ONE lesson with a teacher, and make sure that they understand that this is a "what should I do/not do starting out?".